# Multiple Programs trying to play sound

Tags: sound

Multiple programs can't play sound at the same time.

If I start up World of Warcraft (through wine) with something already playing sound then it cannot play sound. Works the other way round too. Mumble lets me play sound at the same time though.

Some programs like MPD/ncmpcpp won't play sound after I've exited World of Warcraft. I don't know if it's World of Warcraft causing all the problems but that seems to be whenever the issue occurs.

Please let me know if you would like to see the output of any commands and I will update the thread with them.